# Accepts Nested Attributes & Filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Let's say I have two models; Post & Comment

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  before_save :do_something

  def do_something
    # Please, let me do something!
  end
end
```

I have a form for Post, with fields for comments. Everything works as expected, except for the filter. With the above configuration, before_save filter on Comment isn't triggered.

Could you explain why, and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't instantiate and save the comments individually in this case. You would be better off adding a callback in your Post model to handle this for nested comments:

```
class Post < AR::Base
  before_save :do_something_on_comments
  def do_something_on_comments
    comments.map &:do_something
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But let's say that I want to avoid that technique. Is there any other way to achieve the exact same result? Maybe with some parameters on the association? Something like "has_many :comments, :autosave => true" or "accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :touch => true"?

Answer (score 0):

According to Bryan Helmkamp, it's better to use the form object pattern than it is to use accepts_nested_attributes_for.  Take a look at [7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

Maybe you could do something like this?

```
class NewPost
  include Virtus

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_reader :post
  attr_reader :comment

  # Forms are never themselves persisted
  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

private

  def persist!
    @post = Post.create!
    @comment = @post.comment.create!
  end
end
```

do_something would get called when you create the comment.